# preg_match_all undefined offset error

Tags: php, regex, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

Probably there is a regex error here, but I am unable to solve it.

I am getting "`Undefined offset: 0`" error and can't get the value of the title.

Here's my code. INEEDTHISONE is the title I want to fetch.

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= 1; $j++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $site = file_get_contents("http://example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=395&page=$j");      
        preg_match_all('@<div class="name csstwo" title="INEEDTHISONE"><a itemprop="name" href="http://example.com/id/(.*?)/(.*?).html&amp;path=(.*?)">(.*?)</a></div>@', $site, $title);          
        $title[2][$i] = strip_tags($title[2][$i]); // strip tags
        $title[2][$i] = preg_replace('~.*?>~', '', $title[2][$i]); // remove a tag and messy stuff

        echo $title[2][$i]."<br>"; // gives undefined offset error.

}
```

Error in detail.

line24 = `$title[2][$i] = strip_tags($title[2][$i]);`

line27 = `echo $title[2][$i]."<br>";`

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 27


Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 24


Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 27


Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 27


Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test3.php on line 27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
    preg_match_all('@<div class="name csstwo" title="INEEDTHISONE"><a itemprop="name" href="http://example.com/id/(.*?)/(.*?).html&amp;path=(.*?)">(.*?)</a></div>@', $site, $title);
```

to

```
    preg_match_all('@<div class="name csstwo" title="INEEDTHISONE"><a itemprop="name" href="http://example.com/id/(.*?)/(.*?).html&path=(.*?)">(.*?)</a></div>@', $site, $title);
```

and problem solved.

```
&amp;
```

was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change following:**

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= 1; $j++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $site = file_get_contents("http://example.com.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=395&page=$j");      
        preg_match_all('@<div class="name csstwo" title="INEEDTHISONE"><a itemprop="name" href="http://example.com/id/(.*?)/(.*?).html&amp;path=(.*?)">(.*?)</a></div>@', $site, $title); 
        if(isset($title[2][$i])){
            $title[2][$i] = strip_tags($title[2][$i]); // strip tags
            $title[2][$i] = preg_replace('~.*?>~', '', $title[2][$i]); // remove a tag and messy stuff

            echo $title[2][$i]."<br>"; // gives undefined offset error.
        }
}
```

Comment: Returns a blank page, so isset() returns false.

Comment: yes, this is only error free. you may face other problem like match. for that give your input sample & output sample. which will get from `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I solved the problem by changing preg_match_all, but thank you for your answer.